# openssl: unable to get local issuer certificate for accounts.google.com

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I am getting `unable to get local issuer certificate` for `accounts.google.com` over SSL. I downloaded an update CA file from: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and am using `openssl s_client` to render:

```
➜  ~ openssl s_client -connect accounts.google.com:443 -CAfile ~/certs/cacert.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=accounts.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=accounts.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3273 bytes and written 456 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 50C97032E3B74D2CC706CA939CC7FF5EFD40C8D590E8F2B084CD36F092721547
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 1F4565E7707F318C872DA80E1544501E2DA5E0F1508193762D8E61EFB69C2683AE7914D2117E150746F328FAA01CC499
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1490708489
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Not sure how to resolve

Answer (score 6):

*[asonge](https://serverfault.com/questions/841036/openssl-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-for-accounts-google-com/841044#841044)* is correct that the problem is due to the fact that the third certificate in the certificate chain, `GeoTrust Global CA`) was issued by `Equifax Secure Certificate Authority` which is not listed as a trusted CA certificate in the file downloaded from the Curl website. I thought I’d complement his/her answer – and reassure *bcardarella* – by explaining why this is the case.

The list of trusted CA certificates from the Curl website is actually generated from the root certificates used by Mozilla.  The reason the Equifax certificate is not listed in it is that: Equifax and other CA certificates were [removed from Mozilla’s list of trusted CA certificates in October 2016](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/NSS_3.27_release_notes). See the following bug report that led to this change: [Remove non-audited Symantec root certs from NSS](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1288250).

### Cross-signed certificate

The GeoTrust certificate is actually a **cross-signed certificate**. This means that there are two versions of the GeoTrust certificate generated from the same private key (used to sign the `Google Internet Authority G2` certificate).

- self-signed one (now listed by most CA root stores)
- one signed by Equifax

The second certificate was useful back in the day when the GeoTrust CA was first started. At the time, clients would trust it since they trusted the Equifax cert that was used to sign it. Such a certificate is known as a *bridging certificate*.

With cross-signed certificates, there are more than one possible verification path:

#### 1. Using the self-signed certificate

This is the default behaviour of recent versions of OpenSSL.

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect accounts.google.com:443 -CAfile cacert.pem >/dev/null
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = accounts.google.com
verify return:1
DONE
```

#### 2. Using the “bridge” certificate

Here’s a demonstration of the longer chain of by intermediate certificates. I used OpenSSL 1.0.2k and emulated its old default behaviour of not following alternative certificate chains. Since the Equifax root CA certificate no longer exists in my system certificate store, I explicitly specify its use as the CA root store for this one command:

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect accounts.google.com:443 -CAfile Equifax_Secure_CA.pem  -no_alt_chains >/dev/null
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = accounts.google.com
verify return:1
DONE
```

### OpenSSL behaviour

The way older versions of OpenSSL built up a chain of intermediate certificates was to build the longest possible chain from the certificates sent by the remote server and to then look for a trusted certificate that signed that chain. If no such certificate was found in its trust store, it would throw a verification error.

This caused problems as bridging certificates were gradually removed from root CA trust stores and OpenSSL had to change this behaviour. See [Cross-signed certs rejected by OpenSSL because root cert not base of chain](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/openssl-dev-openssl-org-2634-Cross-signed-certs-rejected-by-OpenSSL-because-root-cert-not-base-of-chn-td56649.html)

### This specific problem

In this case, running `s_client` with the `-showcerts` option shows that the Google web server still sends the legacy bridge certificate signed by Equifax’s private key. I suspect that you’re using an older version of OpenSSL (before 1.0.2b) and that it uses all of them when constructing its chain of intermediate certificates.

#### Solutions

Here are some possible solutions to ensure `s_client` shows all certificates in the chain of trust being correctly verified:

1. Upgrading to a newer version (1.02b up) which checks if an alternative (shorter) chain can be constructed that verifies – if the first (long) chain can’t be verified.
2. Some older version of `s_client` accept a `-trusted_first` option which results in OpenSSL checking whether it can build a
   shorter chain using certificates from its list of trusted root CA certificates (*before* attempting to build a long chain).
3. Import the `Equifax Secure Certificate Authority` into your certificate store – or save it as a file and refer to it using either the `-CAfile` or `-CApath` options for `s_client`.

Comment: Phew! Answering that question took over 4 hours. Before I started researching the answer, I knew nothing about how cross-signed certificates worked, never mind how OpenSSL dealt with alternative certificate chains. I don’t know if I explained it very well but I intend to review it tomorrow.

Comment: I wish I could +>1, but did link from my previous and now partly obsolete https://security.stackexchange.com/a/53271/39571 and https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93090/39571 .

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 I came across your *Google Certificates Correct* answer (and upvoted it) earlier while doing my research. I’ll read your other post tomorrow when I’m not doing more important work (or sleeping).

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually an error. This bottoms out in a trusted certificate (the one with the subject `s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA`), but that trusted certificate has an issuer `i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority` that is not in the trusted list. This is actually completely fine. If you look at the final verify status at the bottom, you are properly verified.

Some of the time, the root CA may be self-signed (issuer == subject), but this does not happen to be the case. As long as one certificate in the chain is in the trust, it is properly authenticated.

Comment: To be precise, a root CA is always self-signed. If it's signed by another CA, it's not a root.